# Por qué recibo un único dato a través de GET en mi formulario

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Tengo un pequeño formulario y a la hora de enviar los datos a través de GET se envían bien todos menos el del `checkbox`, que solo envía el último dato que haya marcado y los demás no. No se envían los múltiples datos por así decirlo.

Cabe aclarar que en este caso no estoy utilizando un formulario para el `checkbox`, está hecho en HTML:

**Código HTML**:

```html
<fieldset id="usuallyTof">
    <label>What do you usually do in tof?</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="tof" name="usually_tof" value="explore"/>Explore The map</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="tof" name="usually_tof" value="farming"/>Farming</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="tof" name="usually_tof" value="pFriends"/>Play with friends</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="tof" name="usually_tof" value="kBosses"/>Kill the bosses</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="tof" name="usually_tof" value="uAchivements"/>Unlock achievements</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="tof" name="usually_tof" value="story"/>Complete the story</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="tof" name="usually_tof" value="talk"/>Talk to other players</label>
    
</fieldset>
```

**Vista de django**:

```
def save(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        nick = request.GET["nick-name"]
        email = request.GET["email"]
        uid = request.GET["uid"]
        level = request.GET["level"]
        gamemode = request.GET["gamemode"]
        element_fav = request.GET["element_fav"]
        about_tower = request.GET["about_tower"]
        usually_tof = request.GET["usually_tof"]
        like_about = request.GET["like_about"]

        formulario = Formulario(
        nickname = nick,
        email = email,
        uid = uid,
        level = level,
        gamemode = gamemode,
        element_fav = element_fav,
        about_tower = about_tower,
        usually_tof = usually_tof,
        like_about =  like_about
    )

    formulario.save()

    return HttpResponse('<h2>Formulario completado </h2>')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La manera en la que se envían los datos de un `checkbox` de selección múltiple no es a través de un único valor, si que se van agregando los valores seleccionados a la carga de la petición:

```
?usually_tof=explore&usually_tof=kBosses
```

Por lo que los datos llegan como una sucesión de valores y no como uno único.

La forma de obtener estos valores es a través de [`getlist()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist):

> `QueryDict.getlist(key, default=None)`
>
> Returns a list of the data with the requested key. Returns an empty list if the key doesn’t exist and `default` is `None`. It’s guaranteed to return a list unless the default value provided isn’t a list.

En castellano:

> `QueryDict.getlist(key, default=None)`
>
> Devuelve una lista de los datos con la clave solicitada. Devuelve una lista vacía si la clave no existe y `default` es `None`. Se garantiza que devolverá una lista a menos que el valor predeterminado proporcionado no sea una lista.

Así que puedes obtener la selección de la siguiente manera:

```
usually_tof = request.GET.getlist('usually_tof')
```

Ahora puedes acceder a todos los valores marcados en las casillas de verificación como una lista y, si no marcaron ninguna opción, la lista estará vacía (`len(usually_tof) == 0`).